# Timing issue concerning using JSONP on a form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, jsonp

I'm attempting to use JSONP to push data to server A upon a form submittal on a page from server B.

Here's my JS -

```
my.submitOrder = function () {

    var scriptTag = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptTag.src = ServerAUrl + "?" + urlData;
    scriptTag.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptTag.async = 0;

    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);

};
```

I'd like to have this js execute when the user submits the form so here's the HTML that I thought would get the job done -

```
<form action="http://localhost:3348" onsubmit="return my.submitOrder();" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit"  />
</form>
```

The submit happens fine, the submitOrder function executes, but my call to the ServerAUrl is "canceled" (according to firebug) before it hits server A. Actually, it succeeds about 1 out of 5 times, but there doesn't seem to be a pattern to it. I know something like this is possible since Google Analytics does it. Any ideas?

Comment: Neither `ServerAUrl` nor `urlData` have values?

Comment: These are snippets, the JS runs fine, the issue is that the request to server A is canceled when the form submit kicks in.

Comment: Does your jsonp function have any callback functionality? Also, why don't you use a normal Ajax request?

Comment: This is a piece of javascript that is supposed to be put on client's pages so we can't really hold up the form submittal to wait for a callback.

Comment: We're not using Ajax because this is cross-domain and we would like to support IE7.

Comment: Ajax can be cross-domain, too. But yes, you will need to wait for the callback before unloading the page. Why do you think you could not hold up the form?

Answer (score 1):

You did not prevent the submit event, so the form is sent as usual with loading the target page. In the process of unloading, open requests (such as the JSONP script) are canceled.

To prevent the default action of the event, call its [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) method (especially when using [advanced event registration](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) or just `return false` from your inline-handler. Currently, you are returning `undefined`.

Comment: I don't want to cancel the form post though. I'd like to send the data to server A and also submit the form.

Comment: Uh, why that? However, you will need to prevent default submit, wait until the jsonp request succeeds, and then you can manually submit it via `myform.submit()`